# Problem connecting to virtual machine in Azure using Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio

Until yesterday I could connect to a virtual machine in Azure that has Linux OS through Visual Studio via SSH.
Today I couldn't and I didn't change the configuration.
This is the message that Visual Studio throws me when I try to connect.
Does anyone know what could be happening? Thanks in advance

```
[08:52:18.423] Log Level: 2
[08:52:18.456] VS Code version: 1.85.1
[08:52:18.456] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.107.1
[08:52:18.456] win32 x64
[08:52:18.485] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+7b22686f73744e616d65223a2242617374696f6e5f4941227d", attempt 1
[08:52:18.485] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[08:52:18.485] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": false
[08:52:18.486] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[08:52:18.486] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"Bastion_IA":"linux"}
[08:52:18.486] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[08:52:18.486] "remote.SSH.configFile": C:\Users\ds01897\OneDrive - Telefonica\Documents\Clave IA\Conexion_IA
[08:52:18.486] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[08:52:18.486] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[08:52:18.486] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[08:52:18.487] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[08:52:18.487] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[08:52:18.487] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[08:52:18.487] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[08:52:18.487] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[08:52:18.487] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[08:52:18.488] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[08:52:18.488] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[08:52:18.492] SSH Resolver called for host: Bastion_IA
[08:52:18.492] Setting up SSH remote "Bastion_IA"
[08:52:18.496] Using commit id "0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2" and quality "stable" for server
[08:52:18.501] Install and start server if needed
[08:52:18.503] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\ssh.exe -V"
[08:52:18.506] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\ssh.exe ENOENT
[08:52:18.507] Checking ssh with "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\ssh.exe -V"
[08:52:18.510] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\ssh.exe ENOENT
[08:52:18.511] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe -V"
[08:52:18.513] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[08:52:18.513] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe -V"
[08:52:18.514] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe ENOENT
[08:52:18.514] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V"
[08:52:18.515] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
[08:52:18.515] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V"
[08:52:18.517] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
[08:52:18.517] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[08:52:18.558] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3

[08:52:18.563] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\ds01897\OneDrive - Telefonica\Documents\Clave IA\Conexion_IA"
[08:52:18.564] Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 52914 -F "C:\Users\ds01897\OneDrive - Telefonica\Documents\Clave IA\Conexion_IA" "Bastion_IA" bash
[08:52:18.565] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[08:52:18.950] > Ncat: Version 7.92 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[08:52:18.950] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[08:52:19.712] > userIA@52.136.207.180: Permission denied (publickey).
[08:52:19.734] > El proceso ha intentado escribir en una canalización que no existe.
[08:52:20.991] "install" terminal command done
[08:52:20.992] Install terminal quit with output: El proceso ha intentado escribir en una canalización que no existe.
[08:52:20.992] Received install output: El proceso ha intentado escribir en una canalización que no existe.
[08:52:20.996] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[08:52:20.998] Resolver error: Error: 
    at g.Create (c:\Users\ds01897\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:642703)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\ds01897\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:640069)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\ds01897\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:761983)
    at async c:\Users\ds01897\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:722522
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\ds01897\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:725828)
    at async I (c:\Users\ds01897\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:719493)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\ds01897\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:723199)
    at async c:\Users\ds01897\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.1\out\extension.js:2:907003
[08:52:21.002] ------
```

I am trying to connect via SSH through Visual Studio Code to an Azure virtual machine where I have always been able to.
Today I got an error and I `can't.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem... I could SSH from Terminal or even Putty but I just can't use Remote SSH.. It was working perfectly fine till 2 days back